# Session Expires only when browser window not close

Tags: java, session, session-cookies

I am developing a web application in java in which after 2 minutes session will expire. Now I am facing a issue that if my browser window in open, session will expire after 2 minutes and it will logged out from the system automatically.

But if I am closing the window within 2 minutes and again opening the same application in a new window it's still logged in into the application. what could be the possible reasons of it ?

Comment: Are you sure you are still logged in? Maybe you are seeing a browser cached version?

Comment: No I am still logged in.

Comment: Are you using cookies to auto-log to your app? When you close the browser's window (not only the tag of your app) your session is discarded buy maybe you are starting a new session and log into it using the cookies.